# A class from a child component is not applied correctly

Tags: angular, adminlte

I'm doing a web application using Angular 8 and [AdminLTE3](https://adminlte.io/themes/v3/index.html) as my template.

I want to implement the [Loading Style](https://adminlte.io/docs/3.0/components/cards.html) for a card, this code needs to be placed before the .card closing tag.

```
<div class="overlay">
  <i class="fas fa-2x fa-sync-alt fa-spin"></i>
</div>
```

**Working example:**

[image]

```
<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content">

  <!-- Card -->
  <div class="card">

    <div class="card-body">
      ...
    </div>
    <!-- /.card-body -->

    <!-- Loading Style -->
    <div class="overlay">
      <i class="fas fa-2x fa-sync-alt fa-spin"></i>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- /.card -->

</section>
<!-- /.content -->
```

**Not working example:**

When I move the Loading Style code to a reusable component and now this component is a child, the Loading Style is not applied correctly.

[image]

```
<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content">

  <!-- Card -->
  <div class="card">

    <div class="card-body">
      ...
    </div>
    <!-- /.card-body -->

    <!-- Loading Style -->
    <app-card-loading-state [isLoading]="true"></app-card-loading-state>

  </div>
  <!-- /.card -->

</section>
<!-- /.content -->
```

**CardLoadingStateComponent**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-card-loading-state',
  template: '
             <div class="overlay" *ngIf="isLoading">
               <i class="fas fa-2x fa-sync-alt fa-spin"></i>
             </div>
           ',
})
export class CardLoadingStateComponent {
  @Input() isLoading = false;
}
```

I have tried to apply `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` and `host: {class: 'card'}`, but, no luck.

--

The `overlay` class is located [here](https://adminlte.io/themes/dev/AdminLTE/dist/css/adminlte.min.css), inside of the template's CSS. I inject that file in my `angular.json`.

```
"styles": [
      "node_modules/admin-lte/dist/css/adminlte.min.css",
      "src/styles.scss"
          ],
```

--

My goal is to apply the CSS of the CardLoadingStateComponent correctly when this is a child component.

Comment: Where is `overlay` class defined?

Comment: @ysf Hi, is [here](https://adminlte.io/themes/dev/AdminLTE/dist/css/adminlte.min.css), inside of the template's CSS. I inject that file in my `angular.json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure but I suspect that `.overlay` class is used as a selector in a way that `.card > .overlay` which requires `.overlay` to be a direct children of `.card`

When you use `.overlay` in a child component, it is no longer a direct children because of the component selector tag in between. That's why `.card > .overlay` doesn't work anymore.

Using an attribute selector for child component, in order to get rid of component selector tag in DOM, may solve the problem.

```js
@Component({
  selector: '[app-card-loading-state]',
  template: '<i class="fas fa-2x fa-sync-alt fa-spin"></i>',
})
export class CardLoadingStateComponent {
  @HostBinding('class.overlay') overlay = true
}
```

```html
<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content">

  <!-- Card -->
  <div class="card">

    <div class="card-body">
      ...
    </div>
    <!-- /.card-body -->

    <!-- Loading Style -->
    <div app-card-loading-state *ngIf="isLoading"></div>

  </div>
  <!-- /.card -->

</section>
<!-- /.content -->
```

Here is a proof of concept implementation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x5xpzr

As i said at the beginnig I am not sure if this is the problem you are facing but it might be. So let me know if it works and i hope it helps.

Comment: It works. Your explanation make sense to me and it's validated in the example that you provided. Thanks.

Comment: I am glad that it helped. Have a nice day.